# How to get soft drop shadow in sIFR3?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, sifr, sifr3

like this

[image]
<sub>(source: [photoshopessentials.com](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/images/photo-effects/displaced-shadows/water-text-drop-shadow.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Can you explain wtf is sIFR3? And can you at least make an attempt to add words to your question besides posting an image?

Comment: @anthony LOL I thought it was only me who didn't know what sIFR3 is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this: http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/sifr_3_hard_drop_shadows/

hope it helps, good luck

Comment: it's hard shadows . i need soft shadows

Comment: just set blurX and blurY inside the sIFR config and you should be good.  the article shows you how to set them to 0, which is why the shadows are hard...